# ffmpeg "rendering" past timestamp given

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm using the following to hardcode the embedded text based subtitles onto a trimmed video of a set length. The output of the video is fine but the code runs unnecessarily long because it "renders" past 00:06:12.

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:06:05 -to 00:06:12 -itsoffset 00:06:05 -i video.mkv -vf subtitles=video.mkv:si=0 output.mkv
```

In the output you can see that both the file size and the frames cap at the -to timestamp but it continues on regardless. For longer videos the process can run for much longer than it needs to. Anyone know what causes this?

```
frame=   20 fps=7.5 q=25.0 size=       9kB time=00:06:05.36 bitrate=   0.2kbits/s speed= 137xframe=   39 fps= 12 q=32.0 size=       9kB time=00:06:06.36 bitrate=   0.2kbits/s speed= 115x
frame=   59 fps= 16 q=25.0 size=       9kB time=00:06:06.99 bitrate=   0.2kbits/s speed=98.8xframe=   77 fps= 18 q=25.0 size=       9kB time=00:06:07.74 bitrate=   0.2kbits/s speed=86.9x
frame=  100 fps= 21 q=32.0 size=       9kB time=00:06:08.70 bitrate=   0.2kbits/s speed=77.5xframe=  119 fps= 22 q=33.0 size=       9kB time=00:06:09.49 bitrate=   0.2kbits/s speed=68.6x
frame=  133 fps= 22 q=33.0 size=       9kB time=00:06:10.26 bitrate=   0.2kbits/s speed=62.6xframe=  149 fps= 23 q=33.0 size=       9kB time=00:06:10.74 bitrate=   0.2kbits/s speed=57.7x
frame=  161 fps= 23 q=33.0 size=       9kB time=00:06:11.24 bitrate=   0.2kbits/s speed=53.5xframe=  168 fps= 23 q=33.0 size=       9kB time=00:06:12.92 bitrate=   0.2kbits/s speed=50.1x
frame=  168 fps= 21 q=33.0 size=       9kB time=00:06:12.92 bitrate=   0.2kbits/s speed=46.9xframe=  168 fps= 20 q=33.0 size=     849kB time=00:06:20.46 bitrate=  18.3kbits/s speed=  45x
frame=  168 fps= 19 q=33.0 size=     849kB time=00:06:22.32 bitrate=  18.2kbits/s speed=42.7xframe=  168 fps= 18 q=33.0 size=     849kB time=00:06:22.32 bitrate=  18.2kbits/s speed=40.4x
frame=  168 fps= 17 q=33.0 size=    1431kB time=00:06:29.52 bitrate=  30.1kbits/s speed=  39xframe=  168 fps= 16 q=33.0 size=    1431kB time=00:06:32.82 bitrate=  29.9kbits/s speed=37.4x
frame=  168 fps= 15 q=33.0 size=    1431kB time=00:06:32.82 bitrate=  29.9kbits/s speed=35.7xframe=  168 fps= 15 q=33.0 size=    1432kB time=00:06:40.64 bitrate=  29.3kbits/s speed=34.8x
frame=  168 fps= 14 q=33.0 size=    1432kB time=00:06:45.21 bitrate=  28.9kbits/s speed=33.7xframe=  168 fps= 13 q=33.0 size=    1432kB time=00:06:46.87 bitrate=  28.8kbits/s speed=32.5x
frame=  168 fps= 13 q=33.0 size=    1432kB time=00:06:50.93 bitrate=  28.5kbits/s speed=31.5xframe=  168 fps= 12 q=33.0 size=    1432kB time=00:06:55.85 bitrate=  28.2kbits/s speed=30.7x
frame=  168 fps= 12 q=33.0 size=    1432kB time=00:06:59.62 bitrate=  28.0kbits/s speed=29.9xframe=  168 fps= 12 q=33.0 size=    1432kB time=00:06:59.62 bitrate=  28.0kbits/s speed=28.8x
frame=  168 fps= 11 q=33.0 size=    1432kB time=00:07:06.03 bitrate=  27.5kbits/s speed=28.3xframe=  168 fps= 11 q=33.0 size=    1432kB time=00:07:08.19 bitrate=  27.4kbits/s speed=27.5x
frame=  168 fps= 10 q=33.0 size=    1432kB time=00:07:08.19 bitrate=  27.4kbits/s speed=26.6xframe=  168 fps= 10 q=33.0 size=    1432kB time=00:07:13.99 bitrate=  27.0kbits/s speed=26.1x
frame=  168 fps=9.8 q=33.0 size=    1433kB time=00:07:19.04 bitrate=  26.7kbits/s speed=25.7xframe=  168 fps=9.5 q=33.0 size=    1433kB time=00:07:20.76 bitrate=  26.6kbits/s speed=  25x
frame=  168 fps=9.3 q=33.0 size=    1433kB time=00:07:24.91 bitrate=  26.4kbits/s speed=24.5xframe=  168 fps=9.0 q=33.0 size=    1433kB time=00:07:29.92 bitrate=  26.1kbits/s speed=24.1x
frame=  168 fps=8.8 q=33.0 size=    1433kB time=00:07:33.42 bitrate=  25.9kbits/s speed=23.7xframe=  168 fps=8.6 q=33.0 size=    1433kB time=00:07:38.47 bitrate=  25.6kbits/s speed=23.3x
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't say exactly why the first one was broken but this produces the same result without the overhead.

```
ffmpeg -y -ss 00:06:05 -to 00:06:12 -itsoffset 00:06:05 -i video.mkv -filter_complex "[0:v]subtitles=video.mkv:si=0[v]" -map "[v]" output.mkv
```